# VBA Worksheet_change macro not detecting change in structured reference table

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I'm having a problem getting a `Worksheet_Change` macro to fire when using a structured reference.  I swear I had it working before so I think it's a syntax problem.

When I reference the target cell using "$A$1" type referencing it works fine.  But when I use a structured reference for the cell that is changed it doesn't work.  The other structured references all work fine.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub

    If Target.Address = "MonsterStats[Monster Name]" Then
        Range("B25").Font.Bold = False
        Range("B25").Font.Italic = False
        Range("B25") = Range("MonsterStats[Ability1]") & Range("MonsterStats[Ability1 Text]")
        Range("B25").Characters(1, Len(Range("MonsterStats[Ability1]"))).Font.Bold = True
        Range("B25").Characters(1, Len(Range("MonsterStats[Ability1]"))).Font.Italic = True
    End If

    If Target.Address = "$P$3" Then
        Range("B26").Font.Bold = False
        Range("B26").Font.Italic = False
        Range("B26") = Range("MonsterStats[Ability1]") & Range("MonsterStats[Ability1 Text]")
        Range("B26").Characters(1, Len(Range("MonsterStats[Ability1]"))).Font.Bold = True
        Range("B26").Characters(1, Len(Range("MonsterStats[Ability1]"))).Font.Italic = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The logic of your code is `If ... ElseIf ... End If`, not `If ... End If, If ... End If`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `If Target.Address(False, False) = "MonsterStats[Monster Name]" Then` or set the value of "MonsterStats[Monster Name]" to an absolute address, like $A$1 (instead of A1).

Comment: That did it!! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the [`Intersect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-intersect-method-excel) method:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Me.Range("MonsterStats[Monster Name]"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        ' do stuff
    End If

End Sub
```